# jQuery form validation. How to prevent error messages appearing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form in jQuery. I have it working, with 1 issue. If i click the submit button twice, the error messages will show twice, stacked on top of eachother.

EG

Name must not be empty

Name must not be empty

```
//Form Validation

//Store checkbox, and checkbox label in jQuery object
 $terms = $('#terms');
 $termsdoc = $('#terms-doc');

//Check if pet name is empty
if($name.val() == '')
{
    $name.after('<p class="error">Name must not be empty</p>')
}


if($terms.is(':not(:checked)'))
{
    $termsdoc.after('<p class="error">Please agree to the terms and conditions</p>')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.last()` just adds the desired content as the last child of the target selection, so what you're seeing is a duplicate element being added.

#### SOLUTION:

You could target `<p>` tags with the class "error" and remove them *before* you add them with `.last()`:

```
$("p.error").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable the submit button in the handler. `$(".submit").prop("disabled",true);`
This would prevent duplicate submissions.